# Ошибка вывода последнего файла из папки

Tags: python

Есть такой код:

```
def last_modified_file2():
    global nCount
    folder = '../video/Camera'
    result = None
    date = None
    count = get_count()
    if count > 0:    
      for name in glob.iglob(folder + "/*"):
        if os.path.isfile(name):
            if not result:
                result = name
                test = name.split('Camera/', 2)
                date = os.path.getmtime(name)
            else:
                date2 = os.path.getmtime(name)
                if date2 > date:
                    result = name
                    test = name.split('Camera/', 2)
                    date = date2
        if count > nCount:
         DataLoad(result,test[1])
         nCount = count   
        end = test[1].split('|', 1)
        return end[1]
    else:
      return '--:--'
```

Функция `get_count()`:

```
def get_count():
    list = os.listdir('../video/Camera') # dir is your directory path
    number_files = len(list)
    return number_files
```

Почему-то не выводит новые создающиеся файлы в директории, а тот который выводит (при первом запуске скрипта) дублирует. Причем порой ощущение, что файл он выбирает даже не самый последний а случайный близкий к нему.

Проще говоря, нужно выводить самый свежий файл, его название и полный путь к нему. Проверка проводится в цикле раз в N секунд (копирование файла из папки в GDrive).

---

P.S сейчас заметил,что обновляется последнее название после того, как создался новый (причем их может до этого появиться 1-3 шт.).

P.P.S Если важно,работаю на OrangePi lite под Armbian Bionic Linux 5.4.43-sunxi*

---

Нашел вариант решения:

```
path = '/video/Camera' # Путь к вашей папке
    
def last_modified_file2():
    global nCount
    dir_list = None
    dir_list = [os.path.join(path, x) for x in os.listdir(path)]
    count = get_count()
    if count > 0:    
       date_list = [[x, os.path.getctime(x)] for x in dir_list]
       sort_date_list = sorted(date_list, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
       data = sort_date_list[0][0];
       name = sort_date_list[0][0].split('/')
       send = name[3].split('|')
       return send[1]
       print('count ' + count + ' nCount ' + nCount)
       if count > nCount:
        DataLoad(sort_date_list[0][0],name[3]) 
        nCount = count
    else:
      return '--:--'
```

Может кто-то подскзать, как такое можно улучшить?

Comment: если хотите советов по улучшению, скиньте весь код. не ясно зачем `global nCount`, если проще передать как параметр функции, зачем `dir_list = None`. совершенно ненужная `;` появилась... приведите весь код, я помогу привести его в порядок

Answer (score 2):

```
from pathlib import Path

def get_last_modified_file(folder):
    res = sorted([f for f in Path(folder).glob("*") if f.is_file()],
                 key=lambda f: f.stat().st_mtime)
    if res:
        f = res[-1]
        return str(f.absolute()), f.name
    return None, None
```

---

Тест:

```
In [91]: full_path, name = get_last_modified_file(r"d:\download")

In [92]: full_path
Out[92]: 'd:\\download\\data.txt'

In [93]: name
Out[93]: 'data.txt'
```